# Regex to capture multiple element

Tags: regex, proxysql

I was writting a regex to capture the mysql query execute in proxysql.

my expectation of the regex will capture the following commend where email, password, or both of them appear together:

```
SELECT email FROM user_tbl
SELECT password FROM user_tbl
SELECT col1, email FROM user_tbl
SELECT email, password FROM user_tbl
```

but with my regex it only capture 1 time my regex will be like this

```
^SELECT\s(.*)(email|password)(.*)FROM\suser_tbl
```

Is it possible archive what i want ?

A regex which could capture various element

Comment: It looks to me you can match anything between two strings with `^SELECT\s+(.*?)\s+FROM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookahead assertion `(?=<expr>)` to make sure email and password are in the query.

Using this regular expression covers your examples given:

`SELECT\s+((?=.*?(email|password)).*?)\s+user_tbl`

I took the freedom to change `\s` to `\s+` since it is allowed to use newlines and indentation as well.

See demo below where I also added another query which doesn't contain `email` or `password` to prove it doesn't find those (demo is for JavaScript and just for demonstration purposes):

```js
var sql = 'SELECT email FROM user_tbl\
SELECT password FROM user_tbl\
SELECT col1, email FROM user_tbl\
SELECT email, password FROM user_tbl\
SELECT col1, col2 FROM user_tbl';

var res = sql.matchAll(/SELECT\s+((?=.*?(email|password)).*?)\s+user_tbl/gm);

console.log(...res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT\b(?:.*?\b(?:email|password)\b)+.*\bFROM\suser_tbl\b
```